# Reverse proxy - can a single server be used to route multiple requests?

Tags: javascript, java, proxy, reverse-proxy, http-proxy

**CONTEXT**

In a Meteor app, I'm using a reverse-proxy to load the content of a third party site into an iframe. This allows me to inject CORS headers into the site, bypassing the cross-origin policy to allow me to make changes to the site. In particular, I'm using the `http-proxy` npm package: https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy

**PROBLEM**

Since each user of my app should be able to load a different site into an iframe and make changes to it, I am wondering if it I need to:

- **Create a separate server each time I make a request** for a new website, or
- I can have a **single proxy server, through which all website requests are passed**

What would this look like - would I be loading proxyaddress/siteUrl into each user's iframe?

Comment: a) do you really need this complexity? why don't to use something like easyXDM? b) you definitelly can use a single proxy-server instance for all sites within your application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ursa - do you think easyXDM would allow me to load a third party site in an iframe, with CORS headers changed so I can modify content through jQuery?